# Zend_Form::populate() error

Tags: php, zend-framework

Ive got some kind of a problem here. When I try this function, it return this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Form::populate() must be an array, object given, called in [..]
```

When I used print_r() to find the values of the 1st argument, the output was this:

```
Zend_Db_Table_Row Object ( [_data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 4 [title] => sd [name] => KG [picture] => http://xx/images/mny4r64mqb.png [show] => 1 [body] =>KB
) [..]
```

So I know, that the object I input is an array. What could be causing this problem?
The model

```
public function getUser($id) 
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
        $row->toArray();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;    
    }
```

The controller:

```
 $albums = new Admin_Model_Users ();
                    //print_r($albums->getUser($id));
                    $form->populate ( $albums->getUser ( $id ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert **Zend_Db_Table_Row** to array using **toArray()** and then pass to **populate()**.

[Zend_Db_Table_Row](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html)

**Example:**

```
$bugs = new Bugs();
$row = $bugs->fetchRow($bugs->select()->where('bug_id = ?', 1));

// Get the column/value associative array from the Row object
$rowArray = $row->toArray();

// Now use it as a normal array
foreach ($rowArray as $column => $value) {
    echo "Column: $column\n";
    echo "Value:  $value\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve the problem. There must be some sort of a glitch here. Ill try to work this out

Comment: Added the model and the controller part

Comment: I had an error in my code. Instead of doing $row->toArray() on it's own line, I should have added it to the fetchRow()->toArray().
Thanks, solved!